# Peut-on personnifier un fleuve en français ?

Tags: figure-de-style

En essayant une description du Delta du Danube de la manière suivante:

> Le Delta du Danube c’est l'endroit où le fleuve fait don de sa vie à la gloutonne Mer Noire

pourriez vous me dire si ça a (quelque) sens en français, s’il vous plaît?

Je vous prie de vous concentrer seulement sur l’expression “le fleuve fait don de sa vie” afin de me faire parvenir votre opinion en ce qui concerne la possibilité en français de personnifier un fleuve ou bien de le traiter comme un être vivant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Can a river be enlivened in French? Can it be personified (treated like a living creature)?*

Oui bien sûr, et pas seulement les rivières. Pour citer des exemples dans le Sud-Ouest de la France, beaucoup d'anciens disent *Garonne* sans l'article pour personnifier le fleuve. Dans les Pyrénées, le pic du midi d'Ossau est appelé *Jean-Pierre* (le géant de pierre) par ses riverains.

Comment: Jean-géant je n’ai le su pas, merci beaucoup.+1